# Could a feature be made that lets you upload code directly?

Tags: feature-request

When posting MWEs, I always make a file in my editor, then copy-paste it, then turn it into preformatted text. It would be more convenient (and foolproof) to just save it, then click a button on SE with "Upload code" ... Does anyone else think this might be a good idea?

Comment: I don't think it would be a good idea, mainly because people will upload their entire `mythesis.tex` file rather than spending the time to create a proper MWE more often than they already do.

Answer (score 10):

The feature would simplify posting codes for both questions and answers -- this is true.

However, I don't think this idea is useful in general (we had similar questions why TeX.SX does not provide online-compilation etc.)

As @PaulGessler stated: People would upload a bunch of files, their thesis, not focussing on the main issue.

Other reasons

- People often forget to strip personal data (mail addresses, phone numbers etc.) from their posts then. 
  A MWE does not prevent doing such mistakes of course ;-)
- Uploading the document text does not solve the issue about potential missing graphics or `.bib` files.
- Since documents often have `\include{chapter/foo}` statements, this would either mean that the servers of SX should maintain a similar directory structure per post or to transform this into something that is being downloadable with a click (as it has been uploaded before)